# How to prevent physics body from changing x position in Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, box2d, sprite-kit

I have an endless runner game, my main character has a physics body, I use it to handle jumping.
Everything is great before he collides with obstacles. He starts shifting back, and I want him to stay on his x position at all times.

I tried setting the body dynamic to NO, but this stops jumping.

How do I go about this? I don't want character to move on the x axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do this on the update method

```
- (void)didSimulatePhysics {

    CGPoint fixedXPos = myCharacter.position;
    fixedXPos.x = fixedX;

    [myCharacter setPosition:fixedXPos];
}
```

Comment: actually this should be in didSimulatePhysics, if you use update the node will have been drawn at the physics calculated position before being set back in update. This can lead to the node jittering more or less noticably about the desired x coordinate.

Comment: ok, you are right. I have done it in the past with objects that were not moving fast so the jittering was not noticeable, but you are right. Doing it on didSimulatePhysics solve the problem. I have changed that.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use constraints

```
let range = SKRange(lowerLimit: 300, upperLimit: 340)

let lockToCenter = SKConstraint.positionX(range, y: range)

node.constraints = [ lockToCenter ]
```

and set the lower and upper limits to the same value for it to be locked in position.